# Average of multiple ptime

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I am trying to find the average UTC time of when a function was called. So I do:

```
    boost::posix_time::ptime  current_time_before(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
    DoStuff();
    boost::posix_time::ptime current_time_after(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
```

How do I go about calculating  the averages between these two times?
I tried:

```
double time_avg = (current_time_before+current_time_after)*0.5;
```

But I get an error on a linux system that seems to have a problem with "+" but not "-" .

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Just looked at the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class) and I'm kind of surpriosed to find no `operator+(ptime)` listed. Looks like + is not implemented. You're going to have to convert the `ptime` to something else that can be added. Perhaps use `operator-` with time 0 to get duration since epoch and use `time_duration`s. They have `operator+` Never done this so I don't know if it's a valid solution.

Comment: @user4581301 what would it /mean/ to add dates? You can't. This is typical: the difference between dates is not a date, but a duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just... write it naturally?

```
ptime midpoint(ptime const& a, ptime const& b) {
    return a + (b-a)/2; // TODO check for special case `b==a`
}
```

Live demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4760ac02920cd8a8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::posix_time::ptime;

ptime midpoint(ptime const& a, ptime const& b) {
    return a + (b-a)/2;
}

int main() {

    ptime a = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    ptime b = a + boost::posix_time::hours(3);

    std::cout << "Mid of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << midpoint(a,b) << "\n";
    std::swap(a,b);
    std::cout << "Mid of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << midpoint(a,b) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Mid of 2016-Sep-15 11:17:10 and 2016-Sep-15 14:17:10 is 2016-Sep-15 12:47:10
Mid of 2016-Sep-15 14:17:10 and 2016-Sep-15 11:17:10 is 2016-Sep-15 12:47:10
```